# Read Character Data in RSS by Dom Parser Android

Tags: android, rss

I have a link rss: http://vnexpress.net/rss/giao-duc.rss .
This is a example about code RSS I need read:

```
<item>
<title>Các đại học không được hạ chỉ tiêu tuyển thẳng</title>
<description>
<![CDATA[
<a href="http://vnexpress.net/tin-tuc/giao-duc/tuyen-sinh/cac-dai-hoc-khong-duoc-ha-chi-tieu-tuyen-thang-3374856.html"><img width=130 height=100 src="http://img.f32.vnecdn.net/2016/03/23/thi-THPT-quoc-gia-3446-1458721820_180x108.jpg" ></a></br>Chỉ tiêu tuyển thẳng ở các ngành mới do trường công bố không được vượt quá 25% tổng số thí sinh được tuyển thẳng năm 2016.
]]>
</description>
<link>
http://vnexpress.net/tin-tuc/giao-duc/tuyen-sinh/cac-dai-hoc-khong-duoc-ha-chi-tieu-tuyen-thang-3374856.html
</link>
</item>
```

I want to take link img and display on ListView Custom. I can read tags title, link, but I can't read Character Data in tag  by DOM Parser.

Comment: Maybe you could show your parser code to show what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDATA is not a tag.its part of the value. Read tag 'description'

Comment: OK. But how to extract data from the img tag from the tag description?

Comment: That you have to read the data of tag description and either use "split" function or you can use any HTML parsers.

If your data structure is constant, you can split the data with 'src="' delimiter and parse the link accordingly